# Searching a genome .txt file for specific instances in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to search .txt files containing genomes for specif instances of 'G' and 'C', I am able to get the program to work by copying and pasting the code into the program but I cannot figure out how to get it from the file.  I'm guessing that the problem is that the code spans multiple lines but do not know how to solve for it.

**Here is the code I have been using which works when copying code into python:**

```
sequence='**strings of code**'
found=0

size(400, 100)
background(0)
fill(255)

for letter in sequence:
    if letter=='C' or letter=='G':
        background(0)
        found+=1
        text('The GC content of the sequence is: %', 50, 50)
        text((float(found)/(len(sequence)/100.0)),250,50)
```

**This is the code that I cant get to work now:**

```
f = open('sequence.txt', 'r').read()
sequence=f.split('\n')

found=0


size(400, 100)
background(0)
fill(255)


for letter in sequence:
    if letter=='C' or letter=='G':
    background(0)
    found+=1
    text('The GC content of the sequence is: %', 50, 50)
    text((float(found)/(len(sequence)/100.0)),250,50)
```

Comment: What does "cant [*sic*] get to work" mean? What happens if you run it? Also, rather unrelated: what purpose does those `size`, `background`,  `fill`, and `text` statements have in relation to your actual question? For a simple program like this, it's far easier to use `print`.

Comment: Start with a basic debugging technique: print out `letter` in that `for` loop. Is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

remove this line

```
sequence=f.split('\n')
```

And use :

```
sequence = open('sequence.txt', 'r').read()
```

Long answer:

I will assume that the wrong indentation in the 2nd snippet is not the problem here and the real problem is that it doesn't give you the right answer.

I can see that in the first snippet you used

```
sequence='**strings of code**'
```

This makes the value of sequence a string so that when you iterated over it the letter variable will hold a single character, however when you tried to read it from file you used split over the resulted string which converted sequence from a string to a list of strings, so that letter here became a full string represents every line before the '\n' not a single letter like you used to have in the first snippet

So removing that line will make sequence becomes a string to be iterated over like before